# What Host Name is my application connecting to SQL Server on

Tags: sql-server-2012

We have this 1 node broken cluster that I have been given the joy of fixing. Wont go into the reasons why its only got one node but I am planning on migrating this off onto a newly built cluster.

So the broken cluster is running on a single node "NODE1" on IP "10.1.1.10".

The old SQL Cluster Name has been added as a static entry into DNS "SQLClusterName" and its pointing to NODE1's IP address 10.1.1.10.

For the Migration I am going to use the old cluster name "SQLClusterName" so that we don't need to change a bunch of applications connection details.

The issue I have is that there is an application that uses a database on this server and we are unable to change the app at all. I am trying to make sure that said app is connecting on "SQLClusterName" and not "NODE1".

Is there a way without checking the actual application to see what Host Name the application is connecting through to SQL Server on? For the life of me I cant seem to find this information anywhere.

Thanks.

Comment: You can check `HOST_NAME()` or `client_net_address` (which is Host address of the client connecting to the server) in `sys.dm_exec_connections`. Alternatively, you can use [server side trace](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/TheRockStarDBA/31d781b0fae1de40d0aa/raw/b72c4d25fc7399b64ccc4491f176357c0ba0fc4c/Profiler%2520Trace%2520-%2520sa%2520and%2520logins.sql)

Comment: Thanks Kin, both sys.dm_exec_connections and Profiler tell me the HostName and IP of where the application is and also the IP address of NODE1 but neither tell me what Host Name the application is using to connect to SQL Server.

Comment: If it gets routed through DNS or hosts file, SQL Server will have absolutely no idea what host name the application initially tried. Why can't you check the connection string for the application? (You don't need to change the application to see its connection string.)

Comment: Try running the app from a workstation that is disconnected.  You'll likely get some kind of error message saying it couldn't connect to xyz server.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, if there is no way to check it that is fine, worst case if its connecting on the node1 will just have to just redirect that to the new server until someone can figure this app out.
Regarding the app question, I dont have access to that server and am told by the people who do that they dont know and cant find a way to get that information for me.

Comment: LOL in other words they don't even know what you're talking about

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can install the app on a Windows 7 (or higher) workstation you can perform the following steps to determine exactly what server and IP address the app is using:

1. Start a cmd.exe prompt "As Administrator"
2. Run "ipconfig /flushdns"
3. Run the app, and ensure it connects to the server
4. From the cmd.exe prompt, run "ipconfig /displaydns"

The output from step 4 will show all host names, along with the IP address(es) for those hosts that have been resolved in step 3.  Try to ensure nothing else is running between step 2 and step 4 to narrow down the results displayed in step 4.